# I need Some CSS Ideas for Visualization for visitors

Tags: html, css

I am currently trying to improve the look of my website (beta) for book accommodations and hostels, the site is a basically a directory for hostels.

Well, at front page, you will notice that all headings are almost sharing same color...

However i am unhappy with that, i mean i want to colorize things a bit, but need some advices from css gurus.

I know CSS's basics but i am not expert at it. Soo, would anyone recommend me good colors for headings that suits the current theme of website?

site url is: http://www.pansiyonrezervasyon.com

Comment: I don't really see a problem with your menu colour scheme. It goes well with the simple colour scheme of the whole page.

Comment: are you trying to get a free link to your site?

Comment: @darma i woudn't look for here, if i were trying that...

@Liam Container titles are black same goes for body text, don't you think i should use different container title colors?

Comment: I'm sure you're earnest in your intentions, but this was simply the wrong place to post this question so you can't help but look suspicious. What you need is a forum for designers or something like this, it has nothing to do with CSS, really. When you've got the hex codes but don't know how to change your colors to them, return here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use three sites to help me pick colors when I'm working on a design:

- [ColorBlender](http://www.colorblender.com/)
- [ColorSchemer](http://www.colorschemer.com/online.html)
- [Adobe Kuler](http://kuler.adobe.com/)

Kuler has a lot of pre-created color schemes created and voted on by their community members whereas the other two sites will help you pick and come up with your own color sets.